# Unique List from one column to a limit row length across multiple columns Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-query

So ultimately what i'm trying to do is, copy  paste some data into another sheet.  What i want to do with that data.  Is to remove any duplicate data, and create multiple columns of a fixed length.   E.I.  I have unique 14000 entries.  It will create 3 columns to 5000 of unique entries each.

Short explanation, I have a long ass column of data I want to break up into several columns with a size limit.

So what I was able to figure out so far is

```
=unique(QUERY(Sheet2!A:I,"Select B limit 5000"))
```

Would it be something like by chance?

```
=unique({QUERY(Sheet2!A:I,"Select B limit 5000");A:A;B:B;C:C})
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: You should be aware that sharing your spreadsheet will unavoidably expose your email address.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how it works but got it to work... and i still need to add in the unique aspect to it

```
=ArrayFormula(TRIM(split(transpose(SPLIT(Query(Sheet2!B2:B30000&","&if(MOD(row(Sheet2!B2:B30000)-row(A2),B2)=0,"|",""),,9^9),"|")),",")))
```

i found it from here
https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/split-a-column-into-multiple-n-columns-sheets/